# A non-lossy aka lossless codec without patent-restrictions for audio?

Tags: compression

The term `non-lossy codec` means the coding thing having no compression lost, more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression). I need such format to process the audio, without destroying the quality. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) mentions in the context of lossy compression:

```
Ogg Vorbis (noted for its lack of patent restrictions)
Speex (noted for its lack of patent restrictions)
```

but the other wikipedia site for lossless things is open-ended, it mentions some patents and some expirations but not whether some codec has no patent-restrictions. Does there exist a lossless (non-lossy) codec without patent-restrictions or some sort of lists/matrix summing up the patent -things?

**Perhaps related**

1. Xiph.Org, the organization behind the multimedia formats and software tools [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiph.Org_Foundation)

Comment: You didn't try googling for "lossless audio codec" first?  It's the first result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FLAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC) is the de facto standard, particularly, notice from the latter link:

> The specification of the stream format can be implemented by anyone
>   without prior permission (Xiph.org reserves the right to set the FLAC
>   specification and certify compliance), and that **neither the FLAC
>   format nor any of the implemented encoding / decoding methods are
>   covered by any patent. It also means that the reference implementation
>   is free software.** The source code for libFLAC and libFLAC++ is
>   available under the BSD license, and the sources for flac, metaflac,
>   and the plugins are available under the GNU General Public License.
>
> In
>   its stated goals, the FLAC project encourages its developers not to
>   implement copy prevention features of any kind.[5]

Answer (score 1):

As of 2012 Apple released their ALAC lossless codec to open source. Qaac has a '-A' command line option to use it.